# Error with hilo in NHibernate - "could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table"

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, hilo

I've genereated a schema for my (SQL 2005) db using SchemaExport, and it's created a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[hibernate_unique_key](
    [next_hi] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I try to add an entity, I get the error "could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table". What am I meant to do?

edit: I've inserted a 1 into the table, and it seems to work. Is this the correct value to have in there?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

NHibernate expects to find a value that stores the current hi value in that table, ie it first runs something like:

```
current_hi = [SELECT max(next_hi) FROM hibernate_unique_key].
```

So all you need to do is seed that table with an initial number, ie:

```
INSERT INTO hibernate_unique_key(next_hi) VALUES (0)
```